# как создать поле с несколькими значениями внешних ключей

Tags: sql, база-данных

Название, возможно, не совсем корректно, но максимально точно описывает проблему. Есть поле, `ShopID` в этом поле мне нужно сделать несколько значений, например: 1, 2 и т.д. Я понимаю что сделать, когда поле является внешним ключом невозможно, но как мне решить мою проблему? Проблема заключается в том, что это поле находится в таблице информации о товаре и товар может находиться в нескольких магазинах.

Comment: а может стоит посмотреть на связь вида товар - магазин, т.е. Таблица с полями `ShopId` & `ArticleId`. на основании которой можно будет получить все товары магазина, все магазины в которых есть данный товар.

Comment: @Bald т.е. создать промежуточную таблицу с этими полями? возможно это действительно выход, спасибо.

Comment: @Денис Да, так и сделайте. Тут вопрос даже не в внешнем ключе. В реляционной БД всегда делают отдельную таблицу, когда надо сохранить несколько значений к одной записи. Хранение нескольких значений одного свойства непосредственно в одной записи нарушает 1-НФ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0 и ведет к сложностям в работе с такой БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы это попробовал *реализовать* созданием *связующей* таблицы, т.е. таблицы в которой будут `id` из обоих таблиц, например:

```
+------------+---------------+
|   ShopId   |   ArticleId   |
+------------|---------------+
|     1      |      1        |
+------------|---------------+
|     1      |      2        |
+------------|---------------+
|     1      |      3        |
+------------|---------------+
|     2      |      1        |
+------------|---------------+
|     2      |      5        |
+------------|---------------+
```

таким образом получение всех товаров определенного магазина сведется к

```
select * from table where shopId=@shopId
```

а получение магазинов имеющих ту или иную позицию к

```
select * from table where articleId=@articleId
```